# Unable to import com.auth0.jwt

Tags: java, maven, jwt

I unable to import Java jwt 3.10.0. in my spring project. Actually I was trying before version 3.15.0 but it was giving me an error in pom.xml

"Dependency 'com.auth0:java-jwt:3.15.0' not found"

anyway I then move with version 3.10.0 which is accepted in pom.xml, but it doesn't importing in project, although I've many updated Maven, restart Intellj.
Grateful if anyone can advise.

Dependency in pom.xml

```
 <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/com.auth0/java-jwt -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.auth0</groupId>
            <artifactId>java-jwt</artifactId>
            <version>3.10.0</version>
        </dependency>
```

Comment: does your project build when executing maven on the console? If not, do you have other dependencies to com.auth0 (check with mvn dependency:tree)? If it works on console, but not in intellij: Are you using the newest version of Intellij, which is totally defect?

Comment: You are right, while checking through mvn dependency: tree I realized there is problem in pom structure, I then remake the project & it works. thanks